# Angular: Issue with Singleton Service implemented via Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have implemented Singleton Service(i.e. ApiService) and i'm using this singleton service in the ProductCatalog Module wherein we have two methods in the singleton Service, `getData()` and `addData()`, which list out data and adds the data to a private data array in **ApiService** service.

we have two components product-listing and product-update. we use this component to list the data from the private Data variable from ApiService.

Expectation is when we use `addData()` method of singleton service it should add new data to Data array and on navigating to /update should list the data from Data variable on product update component with newly add data.

Currently this is not happening whenever we add newData to data array via a `addData()` Method of Single service. we are getting only the initial state of the data array without reflecting the newly added data.

Therefore, looks like i'm missing some step or implementation. please help in resolving this issue.

Here is the reference to the code. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2uyx3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think you are navigating by changing the url in the browser as there is no way provided to navigate in the example provided, which surely would not work as when you change the url you are actually reloading your app, which deletes all data in your app memory.

Your service is working fine, you just need to navigate using the @angular/router, and no it can't handle manual url changes and no **nothing else can** do that.

But it will handle links through `routerLink` more on that [here - router official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)

inside **product-listing.component.html**

```html
product-listing works!

<p *ngFor="let item of sampleData">{{ item.id }} -{{ item.name }}</p>

<!-- Example of using routerLink -->
<a routerLink="/update">go to update</a>
```

it can also handle dynamic routing through `Router` service using `navigateTo` or `navigateByUrl` functions like this:

inside **product-update.component.ts**

```js
 // product-update.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService } from '../../core/api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-update',
  templateUrl: './product-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-update.component.css']
})
export class ProductUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  dataForm: FormGroup;
  
  // do not forget to import the service
  constructor(private api: ApiService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(' '),
      name: new FormControl(' ')
    });
  }

  saveData() {
    this.api.addData({
      id: this.dataForm.controls.id.value,
      name: this.dataForm.controls.name.value
    });
    // Use of router service `navigateByUrl` to dynamically redirect to another view
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/listing')
  }
}
```

But for any of these routing methods to work you need to add `RouterModule.forChild()` to the imports of the module  including these components declarations. Like this:

inside **product-catalog.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductListingComponent } from './product-listing/product-listing.component';
import { ProductUpdateComponent } from './product-update/product-update.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild([]) // Add this to the imports
  ],
  declarations: [ProductListingComponent, ProductUpdateComponent]
})
export class ProductCatalogModule { }
```

If you use this and test your service as it is, you will find that it is working perfectly fine.

But again when you change the url in the browser manually you are reloading your app, which deletes all of the app memory/data unless saved at backend.

Here is the link to the edit project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2m9ri

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `forRoot` in core module. You already provided the service in root:

```
@Injectable(
  providedIn: 'root'
)
```

This means the service is available in the root injector of the app.
The core module is useless in this context.

[Here is your stackblitz code working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3vneu)

I recommend you take a look at Angular's documentations for more information:

[Hierarchical Dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

[Singleton Services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

One thing to note: if you refresh the browser or change the route from browser address bar the state will get lost.

Comment: here i have create core in the main app folder, this is only for reference, i will be having core as library and then i will refer the core in the bootstrap app.